# Mailgun-js GET /messages not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mailgun

I am working with Mailgun-js and I am trying to use the mailgun.get to retrieve the list of messages as a JSON.

```
mailgun.get('/mg.mydomain.com/messages', function (error, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

I changed the "mydomain" for posting purposes. When I console log the body it displays "undefined" however if I were to do /mg.mydomain.com/stats it will actually display stats but I need messages lol.

I hope someone can help me with my problem.
Thank you!

Comment: How have you configured this in the API? Is `/mg.mydomain.com/messages` an endpoint that's been configured for `GET` request? An `undefined` response suggests the endpoint isn't returning anything.

Comment: `var api_key = 'key-XXXXXXXXXXX';
var domain = 'mg.mydomain.com';
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: api_key, domain: domain});` @Dandy

Comment: Did you try accessing this through Postman and check the response? Might give some detail into what's going on,

Comment: So I went a step ahead and now every time I call it, it prints the error message: `{ [Error: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method GET is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
] statusCode: 405 }` @Dandy

Comment: I don't know much about Mailgun, but whatever has configured the API isn't supporting the `GET` request. You need to check the API and set it up to accept a `GET` method.

Comment: Check the API: https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-sending.html It says retrieving messages has to be done using a `store()` action in the form of a Webhook. You can't use `GET` method against the API to retrieve messages. The `store()` action does the GET, looks like there isn't a direct way to do this. The response with be in JSON though.

Comment: Okay thank you I will look into it